# Return All Post from publish to draft

Tags: posts, publish, draft

I do something error, I transfer yesterday all post from draft to publish by my user, Now how can i return all this post to draft ??

Answer (score 2):

Quite easily:

1. Go to your Admin Panel --> Posts
2. Select the posts you want to change back to drafts
3. Under Bulk Actions Click on Edit
   [image: Published to Draft-step01]
4. Under Status click on Draft and press Apply
   [image: Published to Draft-step02]
5. Finished

If you have more posts, just go through them the same way. :)

Comment: Are there another way by MySQL in database, its fast than your steps ??

Comment: @The15Seconds Sorry to say this (and please don't take it the wrong way) but: If you have a difficult time turning the posts back to draft in the first place, I would say **avoid messing with the database**

Comment: How can i do that ??